# No module named 'yaml' when parsing yaml file as argument

Tags: python, yaml, python-3.8

I stumbled upon a weird error here. I run the file like this `python file.py --yaml "somefile.yaml"`

`file.py`:

```
import argparse
import yaml


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__, formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('--yaml', help='The file used for yaml parser', required=True
                        )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with open(args.yaml, 'r') as myfile:
        data_to_read = "".join(myfile.readlines()[1:])

    yamlf = yaml.load(data_to_read)
```

Trying to read the yaml file but I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'` error. However, I have already install `pyyaml` library.

Weird enough if I run the file without parsing any argument, I did not encounter any `ModuleNotFoundError` error. But I get this error `error: the following arguments are required: --yaml` which is expected.

BTW, NO ERROR indicated at `import yaml` either.

Comment: What does `python --version` output? Is it the same Python version that has pyyaml installed? You might have to use `python3` instead of `python` to run Python 3 instead of 2.

Comment: ugh silly mistake! Thank you @NathanMills